# How to get PerformanceNavigationTiming to work properly and show the correct entry type?

Tags: javascript, navigation-api

I am using the following:

```
const entries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry.type);
});
```

But it shows what's in the history instead. For example, if I now `reload` a page, then click another page, and then click the back button, I see that the `entry.type` is `reload` instead of `back_forward`. Sometimes it does show `back_forward`, but I can't tell why.

Is it possible to make it work properly? Or it's just not well supported? I tested it on Chrome